# NGinx caching proxy for Ubuntu packages

Tags: apt, proxy, nginx, https

I have configured NGinx to act as a caching proxy:

```
server {
        listen  3128;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/cache-access.log combined_hostname;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/cache-error.log;

        allow   10.0.0.0/8;
        allow   127.0.0.0/8;
        deny    all;

        resolver        127.0.0.1;

        # Merge /pool/ of all upstreams together
        location ~ /pool/(.*) {
                proxy_cache_valid       1y;
                proxy_store     /srv/cache/pool/$1;
                proxy_pass      $scheme://$host$request_uri;
        }

        # Cache things other than the .deb files themselves per host
        location / {
                proxy_cache_valid       1d;
                proxy_store     /srv/cache/$host/$request_uri;
                proxy_pass      $scheme://$host$request_uri;
        }

}
```

I also pointed `apt`-utilities to use the cache:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://dat.host.example.net:3128";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://dat.host.example.net:3128";
```

This works, but only for package-repositories accessed via regular http. Those, that wish to be accessed via https, all fail (something about "invalid headers").

What am I doing wrong? For the time being I simply set the `https::Proxy` to `"DIRECT"`, but I'd like to cache packages regardless of the method used to download them...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently, [NGinx *can not* proxy regular HTTP into HTTPS](https://superuser.com/questions/604352/nginx-as-forward-proxy-for-https). Its main author just [says: "Use Squid"](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,15124,15256#msg-15256).

Fortunately for us, the SSL-using upstream package-repositories automatically redirect HTTP into HTTPS -- a redirection, which NGinx' proxy will quietly follow.

There is also a [patch for NGinx](https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module) to fill this rather gaping omission, but for the time being we do not need it and can stick with the stock NGinx supplied by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx working as a proxy for an HTTPS backend works just fine. The problem I ran into when doing this was related to the requests sent to the proxied server from Nginx not having the correct SNI (for SSL) nor HTTP `Host` header which, depending on the proxied backend server, are usually required.

You'll likely need a couple extra lines in your Nginx config:

```
# Send SNI information on the SSL request so that the backend can use the correct keys.
proxy_ssl_server_name on;

# Which SSL SNI domain to request from backend
proxy_ssl_name backend.example.com;

# If you're using host based virtual hosting, you'll need to add the `Host` HTTP header:
proxy_set_header Host backend.example.com;

# Optional. Make sure the Nginx <-> Backend connection is using secure HTTPS
proxy_ssl_verify on;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
```

This is what I'm using. It seems to work but might not be any faster. There are probably some tweaks to the caching parameters that are needed but the main plumbing to the real backends works.

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/mirror use_temp_path=off keys_zone=mirror:10m max_size=90g inactive=1y levels=1:1:1;

server {
  server_name mirror.example.com;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  # Let's Encrypt
  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
   default_type "text/plain";
   root /var/lib/letsencrypt/webroot;
  }
  location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
   return 404;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mirror.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mirror.example.com/privkey.pem;

  # Tell the remote/backend server about the client that is really making the request
  #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  # Enable range. If you're proxying large files, you can split them up into chunks to enable faster arbitrary seeks
  #proxy_cache_key $uri$is_args$args$slice_range;
  #proxy_set_header Range $slice_range;
  #slice 100m;

  # Keep our cache up to date
  #proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

  # Prevent multiple concurrent cache updates by blocking new clients until the backend request is filled.
  proxy_cache_lock on;
  proxy_cache_lock_age 35m;
  proxy_cache_lock_timeout 35m;

  # Backend host ssl configuration
  proxy_ssl_verify on;
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;

  # Must match the name of our proxy cache configuration
  proxy_cache mirror;

  # Automatically clean the cache
  #proxy_cache_purge $purge_method;

  # Proxy raspbian backend with Nginx `upstream` block
  location /raspbian {
    # HTTP is fine, right? 
    proxy_pass http://raspbian;

    Force HTTPS connection to backend, even if clients are requesting from us on HTTP
    #proxy_pass https://raspbian;

    # Use the same scheme as our clients. (Why??)
    #proxy_pass $scheme://raspbian;

    # Use Raspbian source
    proxy_set_header Host raspbian.raspberrypi.org;
    proxy_ssl_name raspbian.raspberrypi.org;
  }

  # Proxy Ubuntu backend with Nginx `upstream` block
  location /ubuntu {
    proxy_pass http://ubuntu;
    proxy_set_header Host us.archive.ubuntu.com;
    proxy_ssl_name us.archive.ubuntu.com;

    # Use DigitalOcean's mirror instead, for instance
    #proxy_pass http://digitalocean;
    #proxy_set_header Host mirrors.digitalocean.com;
    #proxy_ssl_name mirrors.digitalocean.com;
  }

  # One could probably get fancy with more granular lifetime controls for cache entries based on the URL.
  proxy_cache_valid 200 206 1w;
}

upstream raspbian { server raspbian.raspberrypi.org; }
upstream ubuntu { server us.archive.ubuntu.com; }
upstream digitalocean { server mirrors.digitalocean.com; }
```